# Why is this pointer type incompatible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This is the code

#### Dest.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <CoreGraphics/CGPDFArray.h>

@class Model;

// snip
@interface Dest : NSObject 
{
    CGPDFArrayRef destArray;

    DestKind kind;
}

+ (id)destWithObject:(CGPDFObjectRef)obj inModel:(Model*)model;

- (id)initWithArray:(CGPDFArrayRef)array;
```

#### Dest.m

```
@implementation Dest

+ (id)destWithObject:(CGPDFObjectRef)obj inModel:(PDFModel*)model
{
    CGPDFArrayRef array = NULL;
    Dest* dest = nil;

    // stuff to create array

    if (array)
    {
        dest = [[[Dest alloc] initWithArray:array] autorelease];  

<path>/Dest.m:63: warning: passing argument 1 of 'initWithArray:' from incompatible pointer type

    }

    return dest;
}
```

Clearly the compiler thinks that array is incompatible with `initWithArray:` declared in `Dest.h`. But as far as I can see, the type is exactly right. I even copied the declaration from `Dest.h` and pasted it in `Dest.m`. `initWithArray:` compiles fine. Adding/removing the `CGPDFArray.h` header file in `Dest.h` doesn't make any difference, the compiler doesn't think it is an int in `Dest.h`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a feeling you're leaving out another warning that's relevant — "warning: multiple methods named 'initWithArray:' found". If I'm right, this is what you're running into:

1. There are two method signatures that go with that selector. NSArray's takes an `NSArray*` and yours takes a `CGPDFArrayRef`.
2. `alloc` returns `id`. This means that the compiler has no idea what class it returns (yes, the compiler is that thick).
3. You then send `initWithArray:` to this mystery object. The compiler says, "Gosh, I don't know what kind of object this is, so I can't decide which method signature is correct. I'll spin around really fast and whichever one I'm facing is the one I'll pick." It chooses NSArray's signature. Then it looks at the argument and says, "Hey, that's not an NSArray! Error!"

The quick-and-easy solution is to change it to `[[(Dest*)[Dest alloc] initWithArray:array] autorelease]`. The better solution is to choose a distinct selector for your method.

Comment: Agreed; something like `initWithCGPDFArrayRef:` would probably be better.

Comment: There was just a single warning, but you are correct nonetheless. I did rename the method and the warning disappeared. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh don't do that. Only `CFArrayRef`s are 'toll-free bridged' to `NSArray`. The `CGPDFArrayRef` however is completely different and incompatible. You can **not** use those as `NSArray`s.

The PDF API sure looks like a standard *Core Foundation* compatible one, but it really is not.

Comment: Where is he treating it as an NSArray?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFArray/Reference/reference.html),

> CGPDFArray header file defines an
>   opaque type that encapsulates a PDF
>   array

so it cannot be used as a `NSArray`.